# Export excel from data table using Open sdk xml

Tags: asp.net, excel, datatable

I am exporting data in to excel using open xml sdk. Now i want that data directly export using data table not by using grid view when i give data table directly into  wb.Worksheets.Add(dt) it give worksheets name exception,secondly i want to save file into some location rather than downloading my code is below.

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("GridView_Data");
        foreach (TableCell cell in GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(cell.Text);
        }
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add();
            for (int i = 0; i < row.Cells.Count; i++)
            {
                dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1][i] = row.Cells[i].Text;
            }
        }
        using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
        {
            wb.Worksheets.Add(dt);
            Response.Clear();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.Charset = "";
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=GridView.xlsx");
            using (MemoryStream MyMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                wb.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream);
                MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
                Response.Flush();
                Response.End();
            }
        }
```